# What is this houseplant with narrow, pointed, waxy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

I got this plant, but I have no idea of its name. Which plant is it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a type of [Aloe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Aloe_species). There are hundreds of species. Positive identification is based on the tiny barbs at the end of the leaves and the thick waxy cuticle on the leaves.  There are some pale spots on the leaves which might indicate that it is [Aloe Vera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera) but most specimens are much more upright so it might have been grown under low light or be a less common species.

This genus comes from Africa but the Aloe Vera species is now grown and naturalized around the world.

Care:

- provide bright diffuse light
- do not overwater! This will cause root rot.
- when repotting use a free draining soil such as tropical plant mix with more sand
- generally pest free
- can be easily divided by removing a stem, letting it dry out and rooting in soil